# BigInteger as neutral symbol

Tags: java, biginteger

I am currently working on an algorithm related to cryptography. More specifically, adding points on an elliptic curve. There is an option where I have to handle a situation like adding a point for example P(x,y) = (1,4) and some symbol for the neutral point e.g. Q=(e, e). The result of such "addition" should be Point (1,4). It (e) cannot be a zero value, because then the point will be Q(qx,qy)=(0,0) and another function will be activated, therefore the result will also differ. Can you assign a symbol to BigInteger?
I need something like

```
if(qx == e){
  BigInteger r1 = x1;
  BigInteger r2 = x2;
}
```

Here is full function:

```
static void addPoints(BigInteger x1, BigInteger y1, BigInteger x2, BigInteger y2, BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger p) throws Exception {
        BigInteger lambda = null;
        BigInteger x3 = null;
        BigInteger y3 = null;
       
        if (x1.compareTo(x2) == 0 && y1.compareTo(y2) == 0) { //same points
            lambda = (((new BigInteger("3").multiply(x1.pow(2))).add(a))
                    .multiply(Modul1.getReverseNumber(
                            (new BigInteger("2").multiply(y1)), p)))
                    .mod(p);

            x3 = ((lambda.pow(2)).subtract(new BigInteger("2").multiply(x1))).mod(p);
            y3 = ((lambda.multiply(x1.subtract(x3))).subtract(y1)).mod(p);

        } else if (x1.compareTo(x2) != 0) { //points are diffrent
            lambda = ((y2.subtract(y1)).multiply(
                    Modul1.getReverseNumber(x2.subtract(x1), p)
            )).mod(p);

            x3 = (((lambda.pow(2)).subtract(x1)).subtract(x2)).mod(p);
            y3 = ((lambda.multiply(x1.subtract(x3))).subtract(y1)).mod(p);

        } else if (x1.compareTo(x2) == 0 && y1.compareTo(p.subtract(y2)) == 0) { //y2 is negate
            System.out.println(O);
        } else { //Point add Neutral Point
            System.out.println("Punkt P + neutral : (" + x1 + "," + y1 + ")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to create a fake object that represents `0` but is not `0` because that would trigger something else? And that object has to be of type `BigInteger` and can not just be `new Object()`? But if that object is supposed to be equivalent to `0` but at the same time not, that would be kinda weird, no?

Comment: BigInteger is a single value, not a tuple, so you cannot have BigInteger represent the tuple (point) `(1,4)` (nor, `(e,e)`).

Comment: If you have to use `BigInteger`, you have to choose a value. You can not have a `BigInteger` that is not representing a real integer value. That being said, if you do not care that `equals` might clash with other represetants of that value, but only has to work with `==`, it will work out of the box as `BigInteger` is **not cached**. So you can just do `new BigInteger(whatever)` and as long as you compare with `==` it will just work.

Comment: Please show more context. You could create a subclass, pass `Object` around, or `null`, ...

Comment: Can't you just write a wrapper like class Coordinates and put BigInteger x and BigInteger y inside? Then you can forbid it to be set as 0 by maybe throwing IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: I edit my question - posted full function

Comment: This looks like the Weierstrass form: y^2 = x^3 + a*x + b. As long as b != 0 you can use (0,0) to represent the identity point aka the point at infinity, since (0,0) is not a valid point on the curve. I think @MrFisherman's proposal is cleaner, and it allows you to create a special static object to represent the identity element, e.g. `public static Point IDENTITY = new Point(null, null);`. Then each time you need to check for the identity you can do so by reference with `==`. You must always return IDENTITY as the result when you get the point at infinity.

Comment: The `addPoints` function has as parameters a mix of point data values for two points, and for the parameters of an elliptic curve. This design then leads to the problem of "defining" at this place, when calling the function, some convention for the "infinity point" `e` on the curve, the neutral element for the addition. This is a forced design, which will cause many troubles when things get more involved? Why not define two classes, one for the elliptic curve, one for a point of the elliptic curve. A point instance may handle two representations, (x, y) ~ [x:y:1] - and `e` is [0:1:0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it a little around. I used String as function parameters for one point. If it is an infinity symbol the result is the first Point, otherwise the null BigInteger is given the value of this String.

```
 static void addPoints(BigInteger x1, BigInteger y1, String e1, String e2, BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger p) throws Exception {
        BigInteger lambda = null;
        BigInteger x3 = null;
        BigInteger y3 = null;

        if (e1.equals("e") || e2.equals("e")) {
            System.out.println("Punkt P + O to: (" + x1 + "," + y1 + ")");
        } else {
            BigInteger x2 = new BigInteger(e1);

            BigInteger y2 = new BigInteger(e2);


            String O = "symbol O";
            if (x1.compareTo(x2) == 0 && y1.compareTo(y2) == 0) {
                lambda = (((new BigInteger("3").multiply(x1.pow(2))).add(a))
                        .multiply(Modul1.getReverseNumber(
                                (new BigInteger("2").multiply(y1)), p)))
                        .mod(p);

                x3 = ((lambda.pow(2)).subtract(new BigInteger("2").multiply(x1))).mod(p);
                y3 = ((lambda.multiply(x1.subtract(x3))).subtract(y1)).mod(p);

                System.out.println("lamda to: " + lambda);
                System.out.println("x3: " + x3);
                System.out.println("y3: " + y3);
                System.out.println("Punkt P+P = (" + x3 + "," + y3 + ")");
            } else if (x1.compareTo(x2) != 0) {
                lambda = ((y2.subtract(y1)).multiply(
                        Modul1.getReverseNumber(x2.subtract(x1), p)
                )).mod(p);

                x3 = (((lambda.pow(2)).subtract(x1)).subtract(x2)).mod(p);
                y3 = ((lambda.multiply(x1.subtract(x3))).subtract(y1)).mod(p);

                System.out.println("Punkt P+Q = (" + x3 + "," + y3 + ")");
            } else if (x1.compareTo(x2) == 0 && y1.compareTo(p.subtract(y2)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Infinity,Infinity");
            }

        }
    }
```